# trying to align an icon to be right next to a text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align an icon right next to a text. I have used the :before tag but it doesn't seem to work? Is it because I am using google icons? Below is the code I want to replicate

```css
.review {
  width: 317px;
  height: 25%;
}
    
.review h2 {
  color: white;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 23px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
    
.review p {
  color: white;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: 0.3s;
  /* margin: 20px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="review">
  <h2>Reviews</h2>
  <i class="material-icons" style="color:#FFF9F9; font-size:20px; ">check_box_outline_blank </i>
  <p class="rec">Most Recent</p>
  <p>Most Relevant</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put icon and text paragraph in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178212/how-do-i-put-icon-and-text-paragraph-in-one-line)

Answer (score 0):

Please google first before asking a question on SO. Just by googling your problem, I found your answer in the first link. It is another question on SO. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178212/how-do-i-put-icon-and-text-paragraph-in-one-line).

Just put both items inside a `<div>` element and use the css class `display: inline-block` as you can see in the example.

```
<div>
  <i class="material-icons" style="color:#FFF9F9; font-size:20px; ">check_box_outline_blank </i>
  <p style="display: inline-block" class="rec">Most Recent</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ah should have done that firstly. Thank you. but there is a slight problem the text and icon are not exactly on the same line. The icon and text are not aligned correctly horizontally and vertically as the text seems to be slightly below the icon

Comment: that you can fix with some css styling. Use padding or margin

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, Your Question is not very clear, but the use of google icons should not be an issue. My advice would be to use css grid for layout issues (since the code that you have provided is html and css).

Here is a helpful link:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

grid-column should solve your problem: have 2 columns, the first one for your image and the second one for your text. You can additionally add grid-row for better layouts

Comment: Hey Mashrur, just a quick note since this is your first answer: if the question is unclear (and it is) and your answer may not be the answer to the question, your answer should actually have been a comment; if your guess about the question was right, you could edit the question to clarify it and answer the question.
Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to put an icon to sit right next to a text as i showed in the image i posted. I'm sorry if you didn't understand the question my fault at my end. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think you want icon with links.
Put it inside the paragraph tag.